# Widget not working on 4.3 version

Tags: wordpress, widget

Thanks for reply I am very grateful Kārlis Millers, dingo-d now my widget it looks how.

```
<?php
    class ultimos_productos_widget_1 extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {

    parent::__construct(
        'ultimos_productos_widget', __( 'ultimos_productos_widget_1', 'tutsplustextdomain' ),
        array(
            'classname'   => 'ultimos_productos_widget_1',
            'description' => __( 'A basic text widget to demo the Tutsplus series on creating your own widgets.', 'tutsplustextdomain' )
            )
        );
    }

    public function widget($args,$instance){

        extract( $args );

        echo $before_widget = '<div class="sidebar woocommerce">' ;    
        ?>
        <h3 class="widget-title"> <?php _e('Ultimate Products', 'pruebadesarrollo'); ?></h3>
        <ul class="products">
            <?php
                $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'product', 
                    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
                    'product_cat' => 'marble',
                    'orderby' => 'ASC', 
                    /*'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => 'marble',
                                ),
                            ),*/
                    );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                    <li class="product">    
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
                            <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    
                        </a>
                        <?php if(is_user_logged_in() ){ ?>
                            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
        </ul><!--/.products-->
        <?php
        echo $after_widget='</div>';
    }

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        // Función de guardado de opciones   
    }

    public function form($instance){
        // Formulario de opciones del Widget, que aparece cuando añadimos el Widget a una Sidebar
    }    
} 


function myplugin_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'ultimos_productos_widget_1' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
?>
```

It was working before of update a to wordpress 4.3.

In wp_debug show me this message:

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

Internet research I found that I should change the next line.

```
$this->WP_Widget('ultimos_productos_widget', "ultimos 5 proyectos", $widget_ops);
```

for

```
parent::__construct('ultimos_productos_widget', "ultimos 5 proyectos", $widget_ops);
```

I dont know what happened?

Comment: In your function widget you don't have any arguments extracted, nor instances that you put in your functions update and form. Also you didn't add the widget to the widget init hook`function ultimos_productos_widget(){
    register_widget('ultimos_productosaluminum_widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ultimos_productos_widget');`

Answer (score 0):

Widget need register after you created it
Just put after your class:

```
register_widget('ultimos_productosaluminum_widget');
```

Or in wordpress style:

```
function register_ultimos_widget() {
        register_widget('ultimos_productosaluminum_widget');
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_ultimos_widget' );
```

See more at [CODEX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget)

---

Comment: Thank you very much, I have performed the changes suggested but it not working yet.

Comment: @carloscardonacabrera some error, notice output? Debug mode on?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments,

I modified the code with the suggestions y this is my custom widget.

```
class ultimos_productos_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'ultimos_productos_widget', 
                            'description' => "5 ultimos 5 productos por categoría" );
        parent::__construct('ultimos_productos_widget', "ultimos 5 productos por categoría", $widget_ops);
    }

    public function widget($args,$instance){
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $ids   = $instance['ids'];
        $query_args = array(
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page'  => 5,
            'orderby' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $ids,
                        ),
                    ),
        ); 

        $r = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        if ( $r->have_posts() ) {

            echo $before_widget;

            if ( $title )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

            echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';

            while ( $r->have_posts()) {
                $r->the_post();
                global $product;
                 ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
                            <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
                            <?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) echo $product->get_rating_html(); ?>
                        <?php if(is_user_logged_in() ){ ?>  
                            <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php
            }

            echo '</ul>';

            echo $after_widget;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo $content;

    }

    public function form($instance){
        $title = (isset($instance['title'])) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Products', 'ndb' );
        $ids = $instance['ids'];
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title :'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ids'); ?>"><?php _e('Category :'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ids'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'ids' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $ids ); ?>" />
        </p>
    <?php

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['ids'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['ids'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['ids'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }    
}

function ultimos_productos() {
    register_widget( 'ultimos_productos_widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'ultimos_productos' );
```

This a plugin and works perfectly.

Thanks.